# Automatic completion of common functions in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

Is there a way to allow TeXShop complete common functions to avoid typing the same word multiple times ?

For example, when you type `\sub` , TeXShop would automatically provide options to complete the word for you. So that you type `\sub` - [ Press TAB ] - `\subsection` ..

I find it tedious to type down common functions repeatedly.

Comment: Hit the escape key :)

Comment: @Jubobs can you please add that as answer to mark it as correct ?

Comment: I think you should accept Mario's far more complete answer instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, it took me a little while to write the answer.  I was trying to get the hyperlink right.  Thank you @Jubobs for the recommendation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to *About TeXShop* (available [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/TeXShopManual-2006.pdf))

> "Auto completion is user configurable. To configure, open the file
>   ˜/Library/TeXShop/Keyboard/autocompletion.plist with TeXShop. Read the
>   comments at the top, edit appropriately to redefine Landweber’s
>   choices or add your own, and save. Be sure to edit and save in UTF-8
>   format if you use Unicode characters".
>
> The source editor supports command completion. Type the first few
>   letters of a word and hit the escape key. The remaining letters will
>   be entered. Hitting escape again will cycle through all possible
>   completions.

Comment: Also, if you don't like using `ESC` to trigger completion, you can set it to `TAB` in the TeXShop preferences.

Comment: But don't overlook the separate "command completion" feature of TeXShop that allows you, e.g., to type `\mt ESC` in order to obtain, in the source edit window, the skeleton environment `\begin{theorem}\label{thm:•}
•
\end{theorem}
•` split up among 3 lines, with the cursor positioned at the first placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way, originally commented by [murray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13492/murray), but deserves more attention, so I'm posting this after testing:

Suppose, you want a command completion for `\textcolor{red}{coloured text}`, which can be used to output `coloured text` in colour `red` (to be used with `\usepackage[]{xcolor}` in the preamble.

1. **The GUI way** (*with less control of course*): type and select `\textcolor{}{}` in the command window, then press `command+shift+W` (shortcut for: `TexShop menu > Source > Command Compeltion > Add Word`). You're now ready to use it on the fly, without restarting your work/ TexShop.
2. **The command completion editor way** (*If you want more advance functionalities like: the cursor jumps to the first* `{}` *while autocompletions is triggered*) Go to `TexShop menu > Source > Command Compeltion > Add Word`. Add this: `\textcolor{#INS#•#INS#}{•}` at the bottom of the file, press `command+s` & you're good to go.

> I believe, if someone takes a look at the entries present already in the editor, he/she can automate all the autocompletion needs by adding simple entries. [texshop](/questions/tagged/texshop) is very versatile & powerful editor, with nearly all features built-in, IMO.

Cheers!