# cleveref command auto-completion in TeXShop

Tags: cross-referencing, texshop, cleveref, auto-completion

I want to start creating clickable links for my equation reference etc. How can I let TeXShop know to auto-complete commands like `\cref` and friends defined by the `cleveref` package? I have loaded the package more than once and have relaunched TeXShop to make sure that the package is already in the system.

I've been using the basic `\ref` and `\eqref` by AMSmath, and my TeXShop (fully updated) can recognize the commands so that I can set up a key (ESC or Tab) to press and activate an alphabetically ordered drop-down list of items with the given initials.

Each of the two-columned `reports` I write ranges from 30 to 150 pages, and most equations and figures have long labels. Without the auto-completed drop-down list, I cannot even begin to generate the links. Is there some common practice that I'm not aware of? Thank you.

P.S.

I haven't tried `hyperref` since according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36312/119235) `cleveref` seems better (and `zref` is less popular) ... assuming the status haven't changed in the past 5 years.

P.P.S.
I realize my question might be closed since it's more about TeXShop and less about LaTeX. This post being closed without getting an answer is not something I'd like to see, but I'll understand if it happens. I have [cross-posted it here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=29282).

Comment: Also posted on [LaTeX-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=29282&p=98824#p98824)

Comment: *I'm going to cross-post at other sites.* Remember that Crossposting is considered bad within the whole TeX community. If you properly leave a link to where you placed your question, the majority of helpers will be ok with crossposting.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the reminder. I added the link in the PPS edit.

Comment: The following posting might help: [Automatic completion of common functions in TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107980/5001)

Comment: @mico I actually have been adding my own words to the auto-completion and have been using them a lot. I just don't see how to prompt a drop-down list (of the labels, which seem to be the BibDesk). When I press ESC at the basic `\ref` and `\eqref`, there's the list, but it doesn't work for `\cref`

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues with the Bibdesk autocomplete in texshop. In particular I've not been able to get it to look outside of the current file I'm working on.

Instead I've reverted to using the built in "insert reference" macro accessible by "macros>insert reference". This command works well enough for my purposes as you can select the start of a reference, for example "fig:" and it will provide you with selection list of all the matching labels in the current project including those in imported and included files.

The best thing about this macro is that it is customisable. Go to "Macros>open macro editor" select "insert reference" and find the line beginning

```
property ref_command : "ref" --...
```

change this to

```
property ref_command : "cref" --...
```

and the macro will now automatically insert a cleveref command when you've selected your label.

Comment: Very creative workaround!

Answer (score 2):

The completion of \ref and \pageref commands in TeXShop is accomplished by the same code that works with BibDesk for completing bibliographic references. That code is supplied by the BibDesk folks. You might try to get in contact with those folks. It would be nice if that code allows some configuration to for which commands it understands.

You might just use \ref and \pageref and the do find/replace after your document is stable.